# <ion-infinite-scroll> calling continuous

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing a news app using ionic. For different category of news I am using same template file and controller function. My controller function given below. I am using ion-infinite-loop to retrieve old news, my callback function is loadMore(). First time when I call a category my code works fine, But when I call other category same time loadMore() calls continuously, as infinite loop.

```
.controller('categoryCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$location', '$state',
        function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $location, $state, $ionicHistory) {

            $scope.category = $location.path().split('/')[2];
            $scope.articles = [];
            $scope.last_id = 0;
            $http({
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: {'path': $location.path(), 'id': ''},
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://www.example.com/article/mobile_api/category',
            }).success(function (newsData) {

                angular.forEach(newsData, function (newsArticle) {
                    $scope.articles.push(newsArticle);
                    $scope.last_id = newsArticle.article_id;
                });
            }).error(function (data) {
                alert('Warning! Home Page Request failed');
            });
            $scope.loadMore = function () {
                $http({
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                    data: {'path': $location.path(), 'id': $scope.last_id},
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://www.example.com/article/mobile_api/category',
                }).success(function (newsData) {

                    angular.forEach(newsData, function (newsArticle) {
                        $scope.articles.push(newsArticle);
                        $scope.last_id = newsArticle.article_id;
                    });

                              $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

                });
            };

        }]);
```

HTML CODE GIVEN BELOW

```
<ion-content class="has-header bar-positive" padding="true">

    <div class="list" ng-repeat="item in articles" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <a  ng-click="">
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col col-25"> <img width="100%" src="{{pic_path}}{{item.pic_name}}"></div>
                <div class="col col-75 "><p  class="item-body">{{item.article_name}}</p>                        
            </div>

        </a>
    </div>

    <ion-infinite-scroll
        on-infinite="loadMore()"
        distance="1%">
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

HERE IS MY route.js

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])  
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider 
.state('example.technology', {
url: '/technology',
views: {
'side-menu21': {
templateUrl: 'templates/category.html',
controller: 'categoryCtrl'
}
}
})
.state('example.wolrd', {
url: '/world',
views: {
'side-menu21': {
templateUrl: 'templates/category.html',
controller: 'categoryCtrl'
}
}
})
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/side-menu21/home') 
});
```

Comment: one question: why you put $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete'); in $Scope.$apply?

Comment: @Naitik, Sorry I tested one case, Its removed

Comment: have you tried after after removed it? and please add html code also

Comment: @Naitik, I have tested problem exist. I have added HTML code also

Comment: please check my answer, i did that way, hope it will help you

Comment: @Naitik tested your code but factory function remain undefined in controller ): I have posted my code

Comment: did you try your service in browser for test? means your serivce is good enough to get data? you can use "Postman" also for test service

Comment: http://www.example.com/article/mobile_api/category?id=1 is working in browser? please test

Answer (score 0):

Remove load more if no more data available and increase the value of distance to "2%"

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="item in articles" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <a  ng-click="">
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col col-25"> <img width="100%" src="{{pic_path}}{{item.pic_name}}"></div>
            <div class="col col-75 "><p  class="item-body">{{item.article_name}}</p>                        
        </div>

    </a>
</div>

<ion-infinite-scroll
   ng-if="moreDataAvailable"
    on-infinite="loadMore()"
    distance="2%">
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('categoryCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$location', '$state',
        function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $location, $state, $ionicHistory) {

            $scope.category = $location.path().split('/')[2];
            $scope.articles = [];
            $scope.last_id = 0;
            $http({
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: {'path': $location.path(), 'id': ''},
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://www.example.com/article/mobile_api/category',
            }).success(function (newsData) {

                angular.forEach(newsData, function (newsArticle) {
                    $scope.articles.push(newsArticle);
                    $scope.last_id = newsArticle.article_id;
                });
            }).error(function (data) {
                alert('Warning! Home Page Request failed');
            });
            $scope.loadMore = function () {
                $http({
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                    data: {'path': $location.path(), 'id': $scope.last_id},
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://www.example.com/article/mobile_api/category',
                }).success(function (newsData) {
    // set it to false if no more data to load
    if(!newsData){
    $scope.moreDataAvailable = false;
    }
                    angular.forEach(newsData, function (newsArticle) {
                        $scope.articles.push(newsArticle);
                        $scope.last_id = newsArticle.article_id;
                    });

                              $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

                });
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:

Some different approach but proper one:

**Contoller.js**

```
.controller('categoryCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$location', '$state',
function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $location, $state, $ionicHistory, getData) {

    $scope.category = $location.path().split('/')[2];
    $scope.articles = [];
    $scope.last_id = 0;
    $scope.app.loadMoreData = true;


    $scope.loadMore = function () {
    var id = $scope.last_id;
    getData.getAllData(id).then(function(result){
        if(!result){
            $scope.app.loadMoreData = false;
            return;
        }
        angular.forEach(newsData, function (newsArticle) {
            $scope.articles.push(newsArticle);
            $scope.last_id = newsArticle.article_id;
        })
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
     }) 
    };

}]);
```

**in factories.js**

```
.factory('getData', function($http) {
  return {
    getAllData: function(id) {
      return $http.get('http://www.example.com/article/mobile_api/category?id=' + id);
    }
  }
})
```

**in html**

```
<ion-infinite-scroll
    ng-if="app.loadMoreData" //set in scope as false if no data is retrun in api
        on-infinite="loadMore()"
        distance="1%">
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: initialize scope variable  like this `$scope.app = { loadMoreData : true}`

Comment: @WaqarLashari yes that will also work, i did same but in different way.

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.directives','app.services',])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if (window.StatusBar) {
  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
});
})
```

services.js

```
angular.module('app.services', [])

 .factory('getData', [function($http){
 return {
 getAllData: function(id) {
      return $http.get('http://localhost/article/mobile_api/category?id=' + id);
}
}
}]);
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
.controller('categoryCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$location', '$state', // 
function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $location, $state, $ionicHistory,getData) {



            $scope.articles = [];
            $scope.last_id = 0;
            $scope.loadMoreData = true;


            $scope.loadMore = function () {
                var id = $scope.last_id;
                getData.getAllData(id).then(function (result) {
                    if (!result) {
                        $scope.app.loadMoreData = false;
                    }
                    angular.forEach(result, function (newsArticle) {
                        $scope.articles.push(newsArticle);
                        $scope.last_id = newsArticle.article_id;
                    })
                    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
                })
            };

  }]);
```

Comment: @Naitik yes for testing

Comment: testing for what?

Comment: As you said using factory function is better method I think, And My API call return valid data also. But y console shows an undefined getData error